# Schema.sql not found on classpath for a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a `schema.sql` file in my Resources folder along with `application-dev.yml` for application settings and it looks as follows:

```
-- Drop the tables
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;

-- Create tables
CREATE TABLE customers (
   id SERIAL,
   first_name VARCHAR(255),
   last_name VARCHAR(255)
);

-- Populate data
INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe');
INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Josh', 'Gruber');
INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Hans', 'Gruber');
INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name) VALUES ('John', 'Doe');
```

But it isn't being exucted while the application boots up because when I try to query it in the program, I get an error saying 'customers' doesn't exist. I've tried manually setting the property `spring.datasource.schema: 'schema.sql'` but I get an error saying `[\schema.sql] resource doesn't exist on the classpath`. I know for a fact it does because `application-dev.yml` has to be the on the classpath for the properties to be even read (which get read and leads to the error of resource not found).

Do I mess around with the classpath or am I missing some property that can specify how to initialize my database every time the application runs in a dev environment?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround solution, I checked if my profile (`spring.profiles.active`) contained `dev` and if it did, then execute the resource `schema.sql`. Which surprisingly is found at runtime by `ResourceDatabasePopulator` with no errors. Below is the code I used as a solution:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

// If the environment is dev, then run schema.sql to reinitialize the schema and repopulate test data
        if(env.getActiveProfiles()[0].equalsIgnoreCase("dev")) {
            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("schema.sql");
            ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(resource);
            databasePopulator.execute(dataSource);
        }
```